Difference between BACI and FAOSTAT export values
I am analysing how Ukraine's wheat exports have changed since the beginning of the Ukraine war. While reading some articles on this topic, I noticed that BACI and FAOSTAT data are often cited (sometimes even both in the same article). My problem arose when I compared the total export data for wheat from BACI with the data from FAOSTAT.
Examples:
2022: 2.68 billion (FAOSTAT) vs. 3.27 billion (BACI) from ECO
FAOSTAT claims that is has to official data, which I believe but the number from BACI is more often found in articles. Do you know why there is a difference?
Additional question: Is there also a possibility to see the total exports of the past year on ECO? I can only see the distribution of past exports, but not the total.

Found the answer: BACI's approach is import based so it often includes costs like shipping (CIF). FAO is often (FOB) free on board which includes the goods' costs and the costs until they are loaded on a ship at the port of departure. This could explain at least part of the difference
